# in my code i have a php code tag and i need to insert html code table in the php tag?

Tags: php, html

i have a php tag and i need to place a table by using html  in the php tag code.

```
<div id="box3" class="information">
<?
echo "SHIFT : " . $details['Shift'] . "</br>";
echo "ALARMS    : " . $details['alarms'] . "</br>";
echo " Actions Taken : " . $details['Actions Taken'] . "</br>";
echo "Suppression Apparatus   : " . $details['Suppression Apparatus'] . "</br>";
echo "EMS Apparatus   : " . $details['EMS Apparatus'] . "</br>";
echo "Other Apparatus   : " . $details['Other Apparatus'] . "</br>";
echo "Suppression Personnel   : " . $details['Suppression Personnel'] . "</br>";
echo "EMS Personnel   : " . $details['EMS Personnel'] . "</br>";
echo "Other Personnel   : " . $details['Other Personnel'] . "</br>";
?>
```

i need a html code to draw the above list in the table.

Comment: uh... `<table>`? there's nothing magical about building a table using PHP... it's just html in the end, you know.

Comment: You can insert HTML freely around PHP tags. Also, it's recommended that you use the full `<?PHP` open tag instead of the short `<?` as that's not always supported.

Comment: IT seems that you are asking question without trying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
    <table>
    <?
    while(condition){
    ?>
<tr>
    <td> <? your data ?></td></tr>
    <?    
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="box3" class="information">
    <table>
        <tr><td>ALARMS    : </td><td><?=$details['alarms']?></td></tr>
        <tr><td> Actions Taken : </td><td><?=$details['Actions Taken']?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Suppression Apparatus   : </td><td><?=$details['Suppression Apparatus']?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>EMS Apparatus   : </td><td><?=$details['EMS Apparatus']?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Other Apparatus   :</td><td><?=$details['Other Apparatus']?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Suppression Personnel   :</td><td><?=$details['Suppression Personnel']?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>EMS Personnel   :</td><td><?=$details['EMS Personnel']?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Other Personnel   :</td><td><?=$details['Other Personnel']?></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this format to achieve it:

```
<?php
  //php code here
?>
<!--regular html code-->
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><?php echo $var1; ?><td>
       <td><?php echo $var2; ?><td>
     </tr>
   </table>
<!--regular html code ends-->
<?php
  //php code here
?>
```